# What happen to gain ratio when information gain is 0?

Tags: machine-learning, information-theory

I am learning decision tree using C4.5, stumbled across data where its attributes has only one value, because of only one value, when calculating the information gain it resulted with 0. Because gainratio = information gain/information value(entropy) then it will be undefined. if gain ratio is undefined, how to handle the attribute that has undefined gain ratio?

Comment: Presumably the software is smart enough to avoid dividing by zero. There's probably just an if-then statement in the code that checks if there's a denominator of 0. It's common to have conventions for cases such as this -- i.e. define the information gain to be 0 if a feature is invariant because intuitively you can't learn to distinguish classes from a constant feature.

Comment: Ohh, so what does the software do? does it set the gain ratio to be 0? or something else?

Comment: Depends on the software. If the software you're using is open-source, you can read the code.

Comment: I'm trying to code a simple C4.5 for learning purpose. I'll try to find the open source software for that, any recommendation sir?

Comment: Whenever you're writing your own code, it's best practice to write unit tests for that code first, so that you know whether or not your program is working correctly. If you're just re-implementing something, and you're confident that there exists some code somewhere which is absolutely correct, then you jsut need to check that your code matches the reference code.

Comment: @Sycorax , Sir I found some open source code, On that code when IG is 0, then gain ratio is 0, is it right? https://github.com/juliardi/C45/blob/master/src/Calculator/GainRatioCalculator.php

Comment: Hard for me to say, I'm not familiar with that programming language or code base but your reading of it appears to be correct.

Comment: @sycorax which one do you mean sir?, my reading for the code is correct, or the code for if IG 0 then gain ratio is 0 is correct?